# change color of relative layout, and also its child elements

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, click, selection

I have this relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:background="@drawable/pigs_banner_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_games_pighunt_hill" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gluecksschweinjagd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="31sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the selector of the RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight_pigs_banner" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/pigs_banner"/>
</selector>
```

The behavior is this: The relativeLayout changes it´s color as intended. But I want the Child elements (the ImageView) to also get the color of the selector (@color/highlight_pigs_banner).

**EDIT:**
The color highlight_pigs_banner basically puts alpha value on the color. How can I achieve this also on the imageview (child element) by still clicking only the RelativeLayout

I tried adding `android:clickable="true"` to the child elements, which didnt work, and `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` to the relativeLayout which gave me an stackoverflow exception. Anyone knows how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Selector for `ImageView` and `TextView` as well.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" 
          android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector" />
```

#### text_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:color="@color/normal"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:color="@drawable/highlight"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:color="@drawable/highlight"/>
</selector>
```

#### colors.xml

```
 <drawable name="highlight">#ff590d</drawable>
```

Comment: hmm Im just thinking how to put the highlight color on the imageview, I need opacity on it. just changing the color wont work I assume. Guess I have to set up a new question for it.

Comment: @dan i though the problem with textView and Imageview Highlight.. Can you edit your question so that i can help you.